# Error: "The request is not supported" when trying to shrink volume

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, disk-management

I have Windows 8.1 and when I try to shrink the C: drive I am getting an error (regardless how much amount of space I choose to shrink is)

The error says: **The request is not supported.**

[image: Here is the screenshot of the error]

What could be the reason?

And how can I solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot make changes to an active file system. You will need to boot an external diagnostic or installation disc: I would normally use `gparted` on Ubuntu Live for this. Of course, it goes without saying that you must back up everything before making any partition change - a full disc copy will allow the quickest recovery if anything goes wrong.

Comment: It may also be that some files have been written near the end of the *C:* partition, even though only a fraction of the partition has been used. In that case, when resizing with gparted, MinitTool Partition Wizard or other utility (run from Linux or WinPE media, as @Michael states), you may find limitations on how much the partition can be shrunk.